# How  to make a input method for my conlang using m17n?

Tags: software-recommendation, keyboard-layout, language-support, input-method

I would like to make a input method for my conlang zɪ̀ŋ. How would I go about doing this?
I made one on my MacBook using `ukelele`. Might there be a tool like this? I want it to work like this, when I type:

```
ie1         ɪ̄
ie2         ɪ́
ie3         ɪ̌
ie4         ɪ̀

o1 ō
o2 ó
o3 ǒ
o4 ò

i1 ī
i2 í
i3 ǐ
i4 ì

dz ʣ
ts ʦ
dʒ ʤ
tʃ ʧ
ng ŋ

̤θ θ̤
̤w w̤
`
```

and so on. I use a bit of the IPA character in this language

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: The question is correct but I still have no answer. I was asking how to make a keyboard layout under Ubuntu.

Comment: Cool, I have edited it to push the question to the top of the pile. If it doesn't get an answer in a while, will try and get a bounty on the question as long as you stay active on the site to try the answers that are provided and accept the right one :)

Comment: @nitstorm are you wanting to know the answer to this question also?

Comment: Nope. Not really but more the number of questions on this site are answered, the better :)

Comment: Taylor, if you're into this sort of thing, there's an Area51 Proposal for [Planned and Constructed Languages](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/12409/planned-and-constructed-languages) that's currently in commitment phase. if you're interested, check it out and please consider committing to bring it into beta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick search on [alternative.to](http://alternativeto.net/software/ukelele/?platform=linux) to `ukelele` led me to [Keyboard layout editor](http://code.google.com/p/keyboardlayouteditor/) whose latest version *(although built three years ago almost)* is at [github here](https://github.com/simos/keyboardlayouteditor). According to the site,

> Keyboard Layout Editor is a pygtk program that helps create or edit
>   XKB keyboard layouts. To run the application, you need the python
>   binding packages for
>
> - Cairo
> - Pango
> - GObject
> - lxml
>
> and the Antlr 3.1.2 Runtime environment for Python. You grab that at
>   http://antlr.org/download/Python/
>
> You need to process the ANTLR grammars in order to generate the
>   necessary Python code. All *.g files should be processed with ANTLR.
>
> You can get the ANTLR 3.1.2 package from
>   http://www.antlr.org/download/antlr-3.1.2.jar Assuming you installed
>   Antlr 3.1.2 in your CLASSPATH, you compile a grammar (*.g) with
>
> ```
>   java org.antlr.Tool *.g
> ```
>
> Here is a practical example with Antlr 3.1.2.
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install python-setuptools
>   wget http://antlr.org/download/Python/antlr_python_runtime-3.1.2-py2.5.egg
>   sudo easy_install antlr_python_runtime-3.1.2-py2.5.egg
>   wget http://antlr.org/download/antlr-3.1.2.jar
>   export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:antlr-3.1.2.jar       
>   java org.antlr.Tool *.g
> ```
>
> You finally run this program with `./KeyboardLayoutEditor`